# High load RESTful API in Ruby (sync/async implementation)

Tags: ruby, api, asynchronous, sinatra, thin

I'm struggling with implementing a RESTful API that should return JSON response and should sustain very high load.
The highest load will be generated by 'read' part of the API and very little load will be generated by 'write' part of the API.
My first attempt was to write whole API using nodejs. I almost did it but faced very high duplication of models and logic between javascript and ruby, because the API is a part of a bigger system. I tried moving all logic into backend (mySql), but that idea turned out even more uglier.
My second attempt is to write the API in Ruby ecosystem in order to share models/logic and tests between all parts of the system.

I tried using Cramp and Goliath alone, but all that async stuff really complicated API implementation. I only need to have 2 read urls async because they generate the highest load and by going async all the way I was forced to implement the rest of API in async fashion, which didn't add any value.

My current attempt is to go hybrid: use Thin/Sinatra/Cramp cocktail. I'm instantiating Thin rack handle right in Ruby code and using rack builder I'm splitting API between Sinatra, which is taking sync implementation, and Cramp, which is implementing 2 urls in async way.

Is this is a good way to go? Or having Sinatra and Cramp in one web server (Thin) will get me even in more trouble by some reason?

**update:**
I'm trying solution with sole Sinatra mixed with rack/fiber_pool and em_mysql2. Seems I'm killing two goals - making API async with sync implementation. But I'm suffering from [a bug](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/pull/168) which I think will be fixed quite soon.

Were will be any gotchas going this way?

Comment: When you say high load how many requests per second is it ? Are you caching your reads ?

Comment: It's 200-300 req/s, which pop out to 400 req/s till the end of this year. I'm using memcached. I want to get everything I can out of infrastructure - which is a cluster of 4 amazon 1Gb RAM machines, so this is why I'm looking at async (fiber or event loop) solution.

Comment: Are you, 1. Running multiple instances of thin ? 2. Fronting the thin instances with nginx? 3. Using a load balancer for splitting traffic to the 4 web servers?

Comment: There is nothing running at the moment, I just got estimated numbers and infrastructure. But yeah, it will be running behind nginx with haproxy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to have sync (sinatra) and async (cramp) apps within the same thin process. If the sync part is relatively simple, I'd suggest implementing that in Cramp. A little biased here as I authored Cramp :)

In case you didn't know, Cramp has out of box support for AR/fiber pool - https://github.com/lifo/cramp/blob/master/examples/fibers/long_ar_query.ru

If you decide to use Cramp, I'm happy to help out with any issues as I've been working a lot on cramp recently and am quite pumped up! Just throw me an email!

Comment: Thanks Pratik. After trying different approaches yesterday (goliath, async_sinatra and etc) I finally made a decision that any solution I will go with should support AR (because I want to share AR between API and the system) and should support Rack sync middleware (because I'm want to expose omniauth as part of API). As I understand the only way to use AR in EM is to go with fibers. So my question is - what benefits can Cramp give me atop of Sinatra/fiber-pool? As I understood Cramp gives simplicity compared to EM style way (callbacks), but if Cramp and Sinatra both use fibers than I'm lost.

Comment: Yes, the only way to use AR in EM is to go with fibers. Cramp doesn't have major benefits over async sinatra/fiber-pool unless you want to maintain many open connections or provide streaming API. If you are using sinatra with EM, be sure to checkout async sinatra too - https://github.com/raggi/async_sinatra

If you don't need to maintain a large number of long lasting open connections, why not just use plain sinatra ? Using threads/mysql2 should go a long way as mysql2 C extensions isn't blocking - https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/blob/master/benchmark/threaded.rb

Comment: I won't be opening long lasting connections. I expect to have huge number of fast clients and that's why I'm turning to event loop solutions, because I can't scale infrastructure right now. I didn't get that you said regarding threads and mysql2 - I thought that it's impossible to run sinatra in multithread mode because no web server will run it like that, they only run full stack in a different thread so mysql2 wont be shared between threads - or I'm totally mistaken?

Comment: No, I got you (I read about :lock in sinatra config). So are you suggesting, that for my case (huge number of fast clients) I shoudn't bother with event loop and fibers and just go threads way?

Comment: Also what ruby server actually uses ruby 1.9 threads? Thin single threaded, Passenger uses prefork model. What server spawns threads instead of processes?

Comment: You can use Rainbows! with ThreadPool concurrency model. Thin also has experimental threaded mode ( thin start --threaded ). You can even use mongrel. I can't strongly recommend one solution over another without knowing a lot more about the problem at hand, but working with threads is certainly a lot easier than working with EM.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious what async stuff you ran into with Goliath? In the common case there should be no async code visible to the end developer.

Is there something we can do better to make this less visible to the end user?